# Where are these includes set in Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, ide

In the Project Explorer window in Eclipse, I can see some files listed as included. Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Where are these includes set?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're looking at the include directories which contain the standard headers. They would've been part of the eclipse install and some configuration variable would tell eclipse where to find them when you include one of them in any of your code or header files.